# OpenGL "Segmentation fault" error

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I have been playing with OpenGL and Ubuntu lately and it seems that i have encountered an error.

I have tried to follow other threads that have exactly the same thing as a problem.

Simply put, i did no work...

This is my error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I compile the program using this "build.sh" script

```
g++ -o exec main.cpp -I/usr/include/libdrm -lglfw -I/usr/include/libdrm -lGL -I/usr/include/libdrm -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL
```

And here is my "main.cpp"

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(){

    if(!glfwInit()){
        //error
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glewInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Title", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window){
        //error
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };  

    unsigned int VBO;

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        glfwPollEvents();   

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**:

The problem has been resolved.
For anyone that is like me you need to call `glewInit()` after `makeContextCurrent()`

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see which line causes the problem.

Comment: Just a quick question -- are you in an embedded or otherwise unusual environment (like where the size of an unsigned int may be less than 32 bits).  (Rather unlikely these days, but you never know....)

Comment: Im running 64bit Ubuntu. And the problematic line is glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)

Comment: Why are you calling `glewInit()` *before* `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`?  It won't do anything useful without a current GL context.

Comment: It never said anything about where to place glewInit()

Comment: It is working now Thank you so much!

Comment: for posterity, what fixed it?

Comment: @genpfault -- maybe you want to write it up as an answer?

Comment: Placing `glewInit()` after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`

Comment: @BasyaPerlman: Eh, 64humans is welcome to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple i just need to put

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
```

After the `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`